# QT SDL Not Recognized (Have Qmake File listed. Am I doing it wrong?)

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

Here is my qmake file. For whatever reason, when I try to compile the program SDL isn't being recognized. Why is this?

```
LIBS += -L/usr/include/SDL.h -lSDL

HEADERS += \
    render.h \
    screenwriter.h

SOURCES += \
    screenwriter.cpp \
    render.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems SDL uses pkgconfig:

```
$ repoquery -l SDL-devel | fgrep .pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/sdl.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sdl.pc
```

So the best way to link with it would be to use `link_pkgconfig`, instead of adding it manually to `LIBS`:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += sdl
```

This will automatically modify `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, `QMAKE_CFLAGS`, and `LIBS` for you, by calling `pkg-config --cflags sdl` and `pkg-config --libs sdl`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
`sdl-config --libs`
```

instead of -lSDL ?